# Question regarding Rates of Change

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> (a) Two concentric circles are expanding. At a certain instant the outer radius $(R)$ is $4$m and the inner radius $(r)$ is $95$cm. The outer radius is expanding at the rate of $1$m/s and the inner radius at $0.25$m/s. Find the rate of change of area ($A$) between the circles. Give your answer correct to $2$ significant figures.

Hi, any help with this question would be greatly appreciated
I've tried using the equation A=pi(R^2-r^2) to represent the difference in areas, but I am unable to differentiate it due to the level of maths I am currently studying. Right now, I can only differentiate equations involving two variables ($y=x^2$ and stuff like that).

Are there any other alternatives to approach this question at my level?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Can you please [edit] your question to include what you've tried, explaining what you're having trouble with? Can you write down the formula for the area $A$ (perhaps by subtracting the area of two relevant circles)? Can you think differentiate $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your formula

$$A = \pi (R^2 - r^2)$$

we can differentiate both sides with respect to time (using the chain rule) to find that

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = \pi \left(2 R \frac{dR}{dt} - 2r \frac{dr}{dt}\right)$$

Can you relate the given information about radii and rates of change to evaluate the four quantities above?

Comment: I don't understand what you've done. Care to clarify a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dt} [R(t)]^2 = 2 R(t) \frac{dR}{dt}$$ according to the chain rule, together with the fact that the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$.

Comment: If all I have currently studied in regards to differentiation are equations with only two variables (y=x+1 for example), should I worry about this question?

Comment: The chain rule is pretty fundamental (and this is just an application of it called [implicit differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function)).

Answer (score 0):

Since they are concentric you know they are increasing simultaneously hence find the change over delta in regards to detrimental alpha

Comment: This is high school maths, regarding stuff like:

dA/dt = dA/dh * dh/dt